# Complicated queries with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've recently studied some LINQ sources and decided to use it in the project I'm working on. Everything is almost clear except for one thing.

I'm making complicated reports that make up of several tables. Earlier I used stored procedures for the purpose. I formed several temporary pieces of data that I stored in temporary tables and then joined them together using a series of 2-table joins.

**Trouble is:** LINQ doesn't allow the creation of temporary tables. I know that complicated queries are built in LINQ in a "cascade" way, but if I do it this way,

**Question is:** what am I going to receive in DataContext.Log in the end? I assume it's going to be a really huge query that is impossible to understand and use for debugging. Am I right? If I am, how to find a workaround for this? DataLoadOptions and LoadWith won't do, because I am processing all the data at once and using it will lead to an avalanche of queries.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked at for ex. [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net), then maybe you can combine direct SQL with LINQ?

Comment: I don't want to deal with SQL in any way. That's why I'm using LINQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ definitely allows the creation of temporary tables, it's just any data type that implements IQueryable (Lists being a good example) So if you need a temp table, you just do this...

```
var tempTable1 = [LINQ Query goes here].ToList()
```

and voila, you have a temp table. If you don't like generic variables, then you can create classes and use a `List<tableClass>` instead of a generic.

From this point, you can use the new Var as something to select from while running LINQ queries. If you need it to persist longer, you can store it in Session or pass the variable around.

Comment: I was talking about SQL temporary tables. I assume that placing temporary results into memory and then processing them further in program is much slower than doing the same thing in SQL procedure with SQL temp tables. Point is that in stored procedures I can see each separate query and I assume that in Log I won't have this possibility.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, LINQ does not support SQL-side temp tables. If your temp tables are very large, then you would see the performance hit as you started filling up local memory...but for a smaller table, being able to skip the network lag caused by talking to the DB server can make up for the slightly reduced performance of LINQ queries against C# objects. If you definitely still need temp tables, the unfortunate only way to do it is LINQ to a sproc: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/linq-to-sql-part-6-retrieving-data-using-stored-procedures